Relink Images (Not Missing)
I've seen a lot of posts about relinking/replacing missing images, but all the images are currently linked in my scene, but I want to link them to a different images. This images is used in many different places, and I don't want to replace all the images seperately. I tried clicking the folder icon next to the image, but it just imported the images as a new image instead of replacing the one I had selected.
Maya has a file path editor that makes this super easy! Would be great of Blender had the same thing.
Appreciate the help!

what kind of paths? used in the shader nodes?

You can remap all usages of an image to another one, but the feature is hidden in a special mode of the outliner. In the top left set it to Blender File, expand the Image dropdown, right click on the image you want to replace, select Remap Users, and select the image you want to replace it. You need to import the second image in the blend file first.

